# PHP File Download Android

Tags: php, android, download

I've been doing a lot of googling and I can't get my downloads to work on my android (5.0.1) tablet. I've read just about every link out there and I can't see what i'm doing wrong so I thought I'd see if anyone else can spot my error:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.txt\"");
echo file_get_contents('/path/to/file.txt');
```

I've stripped out just about everything, removed authentication, using GET instead of POST, separate dedicated file just for the file download, hard coding. Above is quite literally the entire 3 lines of code in my code. In regular desktop browser the download works, in android it does not.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

It was an SSL error. I use a self signed cert in my application. So in my app my links are just relative so if the user is browsing under SSL after accepting my SSL the link to download files doesn't work. And since it's not practical to get all my users to install my self signed cert, i either will have to purchase one or devise an alternative way to secure my download links so they're not completely open to the world and the download traffic just won't be SSL encrypted.